# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kats' even after successfully installing Kats

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, kats

I am using google colab and trying to use kats library. Eventhough I successfully installed the kats, I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kats'` when I import `TimeSeriesData` from kats.
Has anyone got a solution for resolve this error?

To install kats in colab, I first

```
!pip install kats
```

This runs successfully.
Then, I run below to import all necessary packages,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

from kats.consts import TimeSeriesData
```

However, running above throws a following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-cec780e07a9e> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
     10 
---> 11 from kats.consts import TimeSeriesData

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kats'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried resetting the runtime?

If you are using google colab it should not be an issue with the python version.

You could try installing the minimal version of Kats with: "MINIMAL_KATS=1 pip install kats" to see if that makes a difference.

Other than that, assuming you have not already tried it, you could uninstall and then reinstall the kats library.

Also might be worth downloading something like anaconda and trying it out in spyder or something.